# Does Identity-Aware Proxy re-use an IP address for simultaneous users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

When using [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule) to tunnel SSH traffic to a VM, the incoming traffic comes from an IP address in the range: 35.235.240.0/20.

If more than user connects to a VM at the same time, does IAP *reuse* an IP address, or does it guarantee that each session will have a unique IP address associated to it?

For instance, if 5 users in the machine at once `who` themselves, would they *possibly* see the same IP in this output:

```
foo_user   pts/0        2021-01-27 18:18 (35.235.241.18)
```

Comment: The answer is not published in any materials I know of. Given that IAP is a proxying service deployed globally, depending on IAP IP address knowledge or patterns would not be a good strategy. Edit your question with details on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Each user will get one IP within `35.235.240.0/20` range, if you want to identify which IP you were assigned once you logged into the GCE instance you can use `w` instead `who` and your IP will be shown with a `w` at the end as follow:

    $ w
     22:18:22 up 9 min,  5 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00
    USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
    foo_user pts/0    35.235.240.1     22:11    0.00s  0.00s  0.00s w

other users will be shows as `-bash` or their respective $SHELL.

But would be more helpful to have more context on this.

Comment: @RaulBautista - Do you have a link for your comment `Each user will get one IP`?

Comment: Related to the link [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule) is the documentation about the IP range.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer elsewhere -- there is no guarantee that different users will connect via different IP addresses.  It could be the case that simultaneous users tunneled in using the same IP address from the `35.235.240.0/20`.